# Download, patch, and build an external library

Tags: python, waf

I'm trying to setup waf as a build system for a project I am working on. Compiling and working with the files already in the project works just fine and was easy enough to understand. However, what I want to do now is download newlib, apply a patch to it, build it, and then use it to compile more files in my project. I'm not entirely sure how to do this using waf. Here's what I have so far:

```
project
+-- src
  +-- stuff.c
  +-- wscript
+-- newlib
  +-- newlib.patch
  +-- wscript
+-- wscript
```

And here's the contents of the newlib/wscript file:

```
def configure(ctx):
    '''
   Configure the library.
   '''

   # tools
   ctx.load("flex")
   ctx.load("bison")

   # locate programs
   ctx.find_program("wget", var="WGET")
   ctx.find_program("tar", var="TAR")
   ctx.find_program("patch", var="PATCH")
   ctx.find_program("strip")

   # XXX
   ctx.env["NEWLIB_URL"] = "ftp://sourceware.org/pub/newlib/newlib-2.0.0.tar.gz"

def build(ctx):
   '''
   Build the library.
   '''

   # download the library
   ctx(rule="${WGET} -q -O ${TGT} ${NEWLIB_URL}", target="newlib-2.0.0.tar.gz")
   ctx(rule="${TAR} -xzf ${SRC} -C newlib", source="newlib-2.0.0.tar.gz")

   # apply the patch
   ctx(rule="${PATCH} -p0 -i ${SRC}", source="newlib.patch")
```

The last rule that applies the patch doesn't work, but even if it did I can't help but feel like I'm doing this wrong. What's the correct approach here? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I would add the downloading step in the `configure` step (and maybe even the `patch` step), but apart from that, I could not see, what should be wrong with this approach.